# Why React Native < Text > component does not show Boolean props?

Tags: react-native

Using RN standard < Text > component with this code I see **"Debug mode: "** text only (but expected: **"Debug mode: true"**).

```
class ClassName extends Component {

  static propTypes = {
    debug: PropTypes.bool
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={...}>
        <Text>Debug mode: {this.props.debug}</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  console.log(typeof(state.debug); //boolean
  return {
    debug: state.debug
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ClassName);
```

Screenshot:

[image]

As described above "state.debug" is Boolean type:

```
console.log(typeof(state.debug)); //boolean
```

The question - why Boolean props does not shown/rendered?

Comment: "debug: String(state.debug)" resolve this issue but the question remains.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Because JSX was designed so. According to [the React documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#booleans-null-and-undefined-are-ignored):

> `false`, `null`, `undefined`, and `true` are valid children. They simply don't render. These JSX expressions will all render to the same thing:
>
> ```
> <div />
> <div></div>
> <div>{false}</div>
> <div>{null}</div>
> <div>{undefined}</div>    
> <div>{true}</div>
> ```
>
> ...
>
> Conversely, if you want a value like `false`, `true`, `null`, or `undefined` to appear in the output, you have to convert it to a string first:
>
> ```
> <div>
>   My JavaScript variable is {String(myVariable)}.
> </div>
> ```

So it's not only about React Native. It's how React works.

I'm not sure about the reason for this design decision, but it is handy that `false` is not rendered for conditional rendering:

```
{items.length > 0 && <ul>{items.map(item => <li>{item}</li>)}</ul>}
```

And it makes sense that `true` is not rendered when `false` is not rendered.

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation and examples.